# Get Laravel base_url in scripts page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, base-url

I developed a Laravel web application.

I included a jquery js file (app.js) into my template and have issue with Jquery appending.

here is my code.

```
if (response.length == 0) {
    $(".col-xs-8 tbody,.col-xs-12 tbody").append("<tr><td class='noEntry' colspan='7'>Not Entries Found !!</td></tr>");
} else {
    $append = "";
    $(".col-xs-8 table thead tr th:last-child").hide();
    var sno = 1;
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $append += "<tr><td>" + sno + "</td>";
        $append += "<td>" + item.job_name + "</td>";
        $append += "<td>" + item.job_max_dob + "</td>";
        $append += "<td>" + item.job_expired_at + "</td>";
        $append += "<td>" + item.user_fname + "</td>";
        $append += "<td><span>";
        $append += "<a class='editThis' href='http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/edit-job-" + item.job_id + "'></a></span>";
        $append += "<span><a onclick='return confirm(Are you sure you want to delete this item?);' class='dltThis' href='http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/deletejob-" + item.job_id + "'></a></span></td></tr>";
        sno++;
    });
    $(".col-xs-8 tbody,.col-xs-12 tbody").append($append);
}
```

**$append += "http://localhost/onetouchcafe/dev/edit-job-"+item.job_id+"'>";**

here I want to place the base url of laravel to solve the migration issue.

How can I solve this..
Thanks

Comment: Please paste your code on fiddle

Comment: you don't need to pass laravel base_url(), just remove http://localhost and it should work,  or if your response did originate from php, just create your href  and return it in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your js file a blade template by renaming it as app.js.blade.phpEnsure that you enclose your code in 
    
Then in your append use the blade template get system to input your route.  (it helps if you are using a named route)

```
append += "{{ route('edit.job', $item_jobID) }}" ;
```

This way you can use the php variables rather than stitching them into your jQuery. You can also change your append and just out put it in the template.

Use

```
@include(app.js)
```

In your template that you wish to include the script